# Why I still get all user when use get method with params for specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4.2.4 with Ruby 2.2.3

This is my users_controller.rb

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: @users
  end

  def show
    @user = User.where('email = ?', params[:email]).first
    if @user.present?
      render json: {info: 'Find a user'}
    else
      render json: {error: 'User not found'}
    end
  end
end
```

This is my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

I am trying to build a Rails API.

When I use this url to send on postman

```
localhost:3000/api/users
```

I can get all users.(total 3)

Then I use this url to send on postman

```
localhost:3000/api/users?email=example.com
```

I still get all users and I am sure that only one user match this email.

Where is the problem? I suppose get {info: 'Find a user'}.

Comment: The route `/api/users` maps to the `index` method, regardless of whether or not you use a query like `?email=...` Read the Rails Guide: Rails Routing from the Outside In: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, which describes in detail how to configure routes that make use of query values.

Comment: Because you don't do anything with the `email` parameter in the `index` method?

Answer (score 3):

this is because this url trigger index:

```
localhost:3000/api/users?email=example.com
```

to solve send your request to:

```
localhost:3000/api/users/example.com
```

and change your routes:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'users/:email', to: 'users#show'
  end
end
```

Comment: this will create a problem when they want to do a single user route, like `/users/4`

Comment: you could add something like, `get 'users/:id', to: 'users#show', requirements: { id: /\d+/ } `  before the email to capture the normal show state..